# UIView Animation IOS

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

Possible so many duplicates of this question , but i didn't find any solution.
I want to slide up my view when user slideup gesture 
here is my scenario

https://app.box.com/s/unt3gyahpx0ax187c5rv

Custom Tabbar is on Top and below is view whci can be slide up/down.

Here is my animation code.

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.topView duration:10 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:

 ^{
            self.topView.frame = CGRectMake(0,-300,1024,141);
             }

completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

But the output is

https://app.box.com/s/fjm1x081jcex1916wyne

I want to slide this view behind the custom tabbar.
I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: What is the name of the other view?

Comment: http://snipplr.com/view/51724/

Comment: above is the custom tabbar

Comment: thanks iPatel i'm looking this solution . I hope it help's me